# How to revert configuration of chmod to run command as root again

Tags: 16.04, chmod, docker

I did `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker` to avoid write `sudo` in all commands of docker, but now I found some information where that solution has a security vulnerability, so I want to revert that to write `sudo` always when I want to use some docker commands.
Someone can help me? Thanks a loot!

Comment: There is no way to *revert* or *undo* what you did. However, if all you did was add the executable bit, then simply remove the executable bit: `sudo chmod -x /usr/bin/docker`. If you forgot to mention other commands or recursive flags, that command won't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/bin/docker
```

Would be the antithesis.